# PHP Issue : Second part of this code never get to work

Tags: php

I'm using single file to put it as  cron in my system. The main idea of doing that is to prevent the cron working 24/7.

I have these lines in my file

```
if(isActivePlugin('plugin', 'first_plugin')) {
    if($expire_one <= $time) {
        $db->query("UPDATE table SET column='0'");
        $db->query("UPDATE table_2 SET column='0' WHERE column='1'");
        exit(); 
    }
}
if(isActivePlugin('plugin', 'second_plugin')) {
    if($expire_twoo <= $time) {
        $db->query("UPDATE table SET column='0'");
        $db->query("UPDATE table_3 SET column='0' WHERE column='1'");
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

But the second one never works and does not check & update the database. Even if I remove the plugin check it still doesn't work.

Comment: maybe a typo here ? `$expire_twoo`

Comment: Maybe because of `exit();`?

Comment: `$expire_one` and `$expire_twoo` are checks from 2 different tables about time stamp value

Comment: `exit()` terminate the current script. Remove `exit()` from the top `if` block.

Comment: Thank you both. Now it's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `exit()` in your first `if` statement is likely the problem. You probably don't want to skip deactivating the second plugin just because you had to deactivate the first plugin.

Generally it is a bad idea to have multiple exit points from a script (or return statements from a function).

See [Should a function have only one return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement) for other strategies